# Dealing with large shapefiles on R

Tags: r, large-files, shapefile

Good afternoon:
I have been studying R for a while, however now I'm working with large shapefiles, the size of these files is bigger than 600 Mb. I have a computer with 200GB free and 12 GB in RAM, I want to ask if somebody knows how to deal with these files?.  I really appreciate your kind help.

Comment: What is the question?  What problems are you getting?

Comment: Large for a shapefile can mean at least three things: 1, a large number of simple polygons: 2, a small number of complex polygons: 3, a large number of attributes. Each of these largenesses, coupled with the type of analysis you are trying to do, has a different solution. What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the latest version of 64-bit `R`, and the latest version of `rgdal` just try reading it in:

```
library(rgdal)
shpdata <- readOGR("/path/to/shpfolder/", "shpfilename")
```

Where "shpfilename" is the filename without the extension.

If that fails update your question with details of what you did, what you saw, details of the file sizes - each of the "shpfilename.*" files, details of your R version, operating system and rgdal version.

Comment: Another option is the `maptools` package, which has a number of relevant functions: `readShapeLines`, `readShapePoints`, `readShapePoly`, `readShapeSpatial`

Comment: Dear Mdsumner and Nullglob, thank you for answered me, I will try do that!, have a nice time!

Answer (score 1):

Ok so the question is more about a strategy for dealing with large files, not "how does one read a shapefile in R."

[This](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/37174/how-can-i-use-fortify-to-create-a-filtered-r-data-frame-from-a-shape-file) post shows how one might use the divide-apply-recombine approach as a solution by subsetting shapefiles.

Working from the current answer, assume you have a SpatialPolygonsDataFrame called shpdata. shpdata will have a data attribute (accessed via @data) with some sort of identifier for each polygon (for Tiger shapefiles it's usually something like 'GEOID'). You can then loop over these identifiers in groups and subset/process/export the shpdata for each small batch of polygons. I suggest either writing intermediate files as a .csv or inserting them into a database like sqlite.

Some sample code

```
library(rgdal)
shpdata <- readOGR("/path/to/shpfolder/", "shpfilename")

# assuming the geo id var is 'geo_id'
lapply(unique(shpdata@data$geo_id), function(id_var){
   shp_sub = subset(shpdata, geo_id == id_var)
   ### do something to the shapefile subset here ###
   ### output results here ###

   ### clean up memory !!! ###
   rm(shp_sub)
   gc()
})
```